# How to access min and max coordinates of a 3D object in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, collision, bounding-box

I am creating a game in qt Creator using c++ and OpenGL and an attempting to add bounding boxes to my scene in order to implement collision detection. I am using objects imported from Maya as .obj in my scene so their dimensions are not set in the code, only their position, rotation and scale. I am able to create a bounding box around each object which matches their position but am struggling to find a way to access the min and max x, y and z values of the objects in order to match the box to the size of the object.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could access the min and max coordinates? I know how to implement the code if I could access these values..

Comment: If you're already able to create the bounding box, then what is the problem?

Comment: @Vallentin - if you have continued reading for another 2 lines, you'd realize this is not the case. The OP creates a "bounding" box that isn't really bounding the geometry.

Comment: I did read it. Taking the min and max of x, y, z of all vertices would create a bounding box that fits. The only case which it wouldn't fit, is if the mesh later is rotated, which OP mentions nothing about being the case for it not fitting.

Comment: Rotation would not be a problem, as the bounding box only has to fit the original mesh, all transformations applied to the mesh are also applied to the bounding box.

Comment: AABB or OBB for bounding boxes?

Comment: The issues I am having is that I can't work out how to access the min and max vertices of the object, that is what I am asking about

Comment: Pleluron - AABB

Comment: @Vallentin, that's only valid for a poligon, but suppose you have a circle, given it's center and radius, you'll have a bounding box that's calculated differently than your proposal.  Let's suppose you have a spline, given its control points.... the problem is not so easy and probably you'll need some polymorphic approach.  This is at least the approach followed in java2d approach, and I suggest reading that api to propose an alternative.  Either way, that's the reason of using the bounding box anyway: optimizing object interaction by means of some heuristic.

Comment: @dtech, nope.  Suppose you have a rectangle (or a square) and rotate it so one diagonal gets aligned to the Y axis, the bounding box will grow in heigth to allow for the larger dimension of the diagonal against the sides.  Your approach is not valid.

Comment: @maria, as you can guess from my comments, the bounding box is something that is dependent of the object geometry and normally each figure class has some means of calculating it from the actual geometry parameters you have.  Probably you'll have it precalculated or some method to allow you to get it.  Check that.

Comment: Accessing the min/max vertices of the object would require iterating over all vertices to obtain the min/max values of each dimension - For an AABB all dimensions would contribute to a single min value and a single max value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you afford is that each object geometry has different means of internal storage and determination of a bounding box.

Let's try some examples to illustrate this:

- Suppose we have a circle, whose drawing parameters stored internally are the center coordinates `x_center` and `y_center` and the radius `radius`.  If you try to determine the bounding box for this object, you'll see that it extends from `(x_center - radius, y_center - radius)` to `(x_center + radius, y_center + radius)`.
- In case you have an unrotated rectangle, given by the two points of it's principal diagonal, the bounding box just coincides with it's shape, so you have only to give the coordinates of the two same points that represent it.
- If, on the other way, we have a polygon, the bounding box will be determined by the minimum and maximum coordinates of all the polygon vertices.  If  you allow to rotate the polygon, you'll need to rotate all the vertices coordinates before determining their maximum and minimum values, to get the bounding box.
- If, for another example, we have a cubic spline, determined by the coordinates of its four control points you'll be determining the maximum and minimum values of two cubic polygons, which means solving two quadratic equations(after derivation), in the general case.

To cope with all this stuff, a geometric shape normally includes some means of polymorphically  construct it's bounding box (it normally is even cached, so you don't have to calculate it, only after rotations or variations in it's position or scale) via some instance method.

Of course, all of this depends on how and how has defined the way shapes are implemented.  perhaps your case is simpler than I'm exposing here, but you don't say.  You also don't show any code or input/output data, as stated in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page. So you had better to edit your question and add your sample code, that will show more information about your exact problem.

Answer (score -1):

if you have obj loader so you have an array.

```
float t[2100];
int x = 2100;
float xmax=-123243;
while(x>=0)
{
   if(xmax<t[x]) xmax=t[x];
   x-=3;
}
```

So here is a maximum x of the object(?).